# Difference between thyristor I(tsm) and I T(AV)

Tags: thyristor, scr

For example
I have a capacitor send intermittent pulses to a coil

send about 85A for few msec then off for 3-4 seconds (for 5mins)

[image]

[image]

I was looking for a scr to switch it

i found 40tps12 thyristor

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/111432/IRF/40TPS12.html

Has I(tsm) 500-600A for 10 msec

And I T(AV) 35A

So should i consider this thyristor can stand with 85A as its I(tsm) up to 600A or can not stand with as its I T(AV) is lower than 85A

Means which should i consider?

Comment: You need to show a proposed schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka updated

Comment: To be sure, calculate I2t and I2sqrt(t) of your pulse ... Be aware of the "large" current when charging your capacitor ...

Comment: For help, this document ... https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/automotive/catalogs/littelfuse_fuseology.pdf

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368780/thyristor-scr-i2t-and-i2-sqrtt-rating

Comment: Yes, that SCR should work. Please follow all the warnings in your previous related posts.